# How can I set width using percentage and get the same width with or without a vertical scrollbar?

Tags: css, positioning, browser-scrollbars

I have an element which I want to have `width: 50%`. But when the right scrollbar is there, that 50% looks different than before, and since certain elements appear and disappear (through animation), the scrollbar also appears and dissapears, dynamially changing my element's width.

See the [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Shawn/htWrC/)

Is there any way I can set an element's width with a percentage and not have it influenced by the presence or absence of a vertical scrollbar?

Comment: Are you sure it is not a font change or margin padding change? Do you have a width defined on the containing element? Posting the HTML and relevant CSS would help.

Comment: When you animate an element with jQuery, watch the css styles change. Make the duration like 15 seconds and watch the css styles change throughout the entire animation so that you can see what may be causing the issue.

Comment: Can't help without seeing the relevant HTML.

Comment: I'd also bet this is tied to CSS. Make sure there isn't something cascading CSS that's effecting your li

Comment: Oh I got it, the additional content was making a scrollbar appear for vertical scrolling. Since the width of my element is a percentage, it changes with the page width, with the scrollbar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make width adjustments to accommodate the scroll bar on the click, but if you are going to have a lot going on that may cause this to occur, it would probably be best to just put...

```
body {overflow-y: scroll;}
```

...and have the vertical scroll bar always be present. See http://jsfiddle.net/htWrC/1/

Comment: same idea, but this is better/simpler than my soln.

Comment: @Faust what was you solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

Check if the height of the `div` is taller than the height of the `window`.

If so, there is a scroll.  Set the `width` slightly wider to account for the scrollbar.

**Code**

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('p').toggle();

    var a = $('#box');

    if(a.height() > window.innerHeight){
        $('#box').css('width', '51.7%');
    }

    else{
        $('#box').css('width','50%');    
    }              

});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/htWrC/2/

Comment: This solution doesn't work, the div's width still varies in your jsfiddle example.